# Spring + Hibernate Transaction -- Native SQL rollback failure

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate

I recently came across this problem -- my transactional method (marked as @Transactional) failed to do the rollback when I use native SQL. If I instead use Hibernate API to save an entity, it did roll back!

> Background

I have a class Employee() and I have a table tbl_employee. I want to use native SQL to insert rows to tbl_employee, and each insertion will insert 500 rows at maximum. For example, if I have 600 employees to insert, I will create two SQL insert queries (one for the first 500 and the other for the next 100). My insert method looks like this (to make it simple, I only consider insertion of (500,1000) rows):

```
@Transactional
public void insert(List<Employee> list) throws RuntimeException{
  Dao dao = new Dao();
  String sql1 = buildSQL (list.subList(0,500));//the first 500. buildSQL is a simple method which build an insert query for the list
  String sql2 = buiildSQL (list.subList(500,list.size()));//the remaining
  dao.executeSQL(sql1);//dao performs the sql query to the database
  dao.executeSQL(sql2);
}
```

And here is the spring configuration. I use HibernateTransactionManager.

```
  <bean id="txManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
         <ref local="mySessionFactory"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

My Dao() class performs my sql to the database and if there is an exception during insertion, I will throw a RuntimeException.

> The problem

I tried to insert 501 employees to an empty table. The first 500 have unique ids and the last one has the same id as the first one. Therefore when I insert the last one, there will be a "DUPLICATE　PRIMARY KEY" error. I expect that the previous insert() method will rollback -- No rows should be inserted to the table. However, I noticed that the first 500 got inserted to the database!

I then tried to use Hibernate API. My insert method becomes:

```
@Transactional
public void insert(List<Employee> list) throws RuntimeException{
  Dao dao = new Dao();
  for (Employee employee: list)
     dao.save(employee);
}
```

And it actually did what I expect! No rows are inserted to the database once there is an exception.

> My questions

1. I wonder if spring/hibernate support transaction management for native SQL.
2. The rollback works if I directly "save" an entity using Hibernate.The reason why I want to use native sql is that I actually need to insert employees to different tables based on, say, the insertion datetime. (e.g the new emloyees this year will be inserted to tbl_employee_2015).Therefore it's easier to map to different tables using native SQL. Is there any other elegant way to handle mapping to different tables?
3. I am assuming that one sql for multiple row insertion is very efficient. Therefore I want to insert 500 rows by one sql. I don't want to do Hibernate save one by one in a loop. Is this assumption correct?

Thank you so much for your attention！

Comment: How are you obtaining the connection and starting a transaction in the class `Dao`?  When you say `one SQL for multiple row insertion`, do you mean `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...) (...) (...)` kind of construct, where there is a single `INSERT INTO` followed by multiple tuples?

Comment: 1. In my Dao, I use getHibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql).executeUpdate(). So I don't manage the transaction myself. I am assuming that Spring does that.  Actually I should not do any transaction management in my Dao, because I do it in my Service class (by using @Transactional annotation) 2. Yes you are right! I use a single INSERT INTO followed by multiple tuples. Thank you!

Comment: I am not 100% sure since I have not used Hibernate directly for many years now, but when I did I always had code like `Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction(); session.createSQLQuery(query); transaction.commit();`.  You could try that since you will have direct control over the transaction.  Also note that you can use [batch inserts with Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#batch-inserts).  This will save you the native SQL and yet give you a performant solution.

Comment: I got your point. I will try that solution if Spring cannot help me. Thank you very much Manish.