# Spring & Hibernate - Make native queries run in the same transaction as @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

Is it possible to create native queries that make use of an existing transaction created via @Transactional?
Most of the questions here seem to be about making native queries at all. Also, answers such as the one from [Spring + Hibernate Transaction -- Native SQL rollback failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196735/spring-hibernate-transaction-native-sql-rollback-failure) suggest it might not be possible.

What I do to test the isolation is to run some deletes and add a breakpoint to investigate the database.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
@Transactional(value = "someManager")
public class SpringJpaSomeDao implements SomeDao {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "someUnit")
@Qualifier("entityManagerFactorySome")
private EntityManager em;


@Resource
@Qualifier("someManager")
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

@Override
@Transactional(value = "someManager", propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public void runNative(String sql){
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS);
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

        @Override

        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {

            em.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();

        }

    });





}
```

Some part of the persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="someUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/someDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <!-- some classes here -->
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <!-- some dialect -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The code is invoked from some controller which also has @Transactional annotations giving the deletes to the Dao.

```
@Transactional(value = "someManager", propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public void deleteEntireDatabase() {

    List<String> deletions = new ArrayList<>();
    deletions.add("DELETE FROM something;");


    for (String currentDeletion : deletions) {
        someDao.runNative(currentDeletion);
    }


}

@Override
@Transactional(value = "someManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
public void deleteAndFill(JobExecutionProgress progress) {
    deleteEntireDatabase();
    // more code
}
```

Excerpt from spring-dao.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven  />

<bean id="entityManagerFactorySome" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="someDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="someUnit" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- some dialect -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="someDao" class="xyz.model.controller.SpringJpaSomeDao"/>

<bean id="someManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactorySome" />
    <qualifier value="someManager"></qualifier>
</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Of course, I also tried some variations such as different Propagations, and using the entityManager obtained from elsewhere:

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = ((JpaTransactionManager) transactionManager).getEntityManagerFactory();

    EntityManager em2 = EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(emf);
```

Now, what I will do if everything else fails is manual transaction management.

Is this something that has worked for one of your applications or is it unknown if this might be a setup problem?

Comment: By the way, for completeness, I have to mention that the delete-Method also contained alter table statements to reset the auto_increment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turns out the alter table statements mentioned in the comment seem to have been the problem. Not sure how resetting the auto_increment can empty the table, but that seemed to be the case.